# Where do the Jubilee names including "Platinum" come from?

Tags: etymology

When was the name "Platinum jubilee" invented? What about the rest of the nicknames? If it's named after wedding anniversary titles, how did those titles come about?

[Cake Toppers.com:](https://www.caketoppers.co.uk/page/wedding-anniversary-names)

> The celebration of wedding anniversaries dates back to Roman times when husbands gave their wives a silver wreath for 25 years of marriage, and a gold wreath for 50 years. **Twentieth century commercialism then led to the addition of more gifts to represent colour and names for other years**. By the 1930's there was a material or symbol representing the year as a gift suggestion for the first year and milestone years such as 10th, 20th, 25th and 50th. **Over the years more were added and the gift list updated and modernised by various American and British greeting card companies**

emboldened the interesting stuff I would like to know more about

Comment: Look up wedding anniversaries: they go from paper to platinum.

Comment: It's an interesting question but I'm not sure it's specific to the English language. Wikipedia doesn't say much but suggests (Wedding anniversary) some were made up by jewellers.

Comment: and by greetings card manufacturers.

Comment: This question is not specific to English: the names are the same in many languages (eg German *Silberhochzeit;* French *jubilé de platine*). It **might possibly** be [on-topic](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on [history.se] but you'll need at least to look in Wikipedia first. I found [relevant information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anniversary#Anniversary_symbols) in around 20 seconds — although their reference says that diamond is not reached till 75 years.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I think just because a phrase/word happens to have similar origins as an equivalent word in another language, doesn't make the question off-topic here. The fourth highest voted etymology question is about "quadratic", which is also the same word in german and french.

Comment: I would dispute that the origin of an expression like "silver wedding" is actually etymology in a similar way to the etymology of *quadratic,* though. You're asking why the word *silver* was **chosen** to mean 25 years, which is not the same as deriving *quadratic* from the same source as *square.* This question should really be retagged, but I'm not sure what to. That in itself may be an indication of off-topicness.